# How to aggregate selective content in a table?

Tags: r

I could do it quite easily in Excel but I am keen to crack it in R. Basically, this is simple table with rows names as respondents age group and column names as a binary indicator (yes/no)

The aim to compare some subgroups results with the total 
Im trying to sum three age groups including 25 to 29,30 to 34 and 35 to 39 who answered yes in the survey and calculate the percentage of 'yes'

I work out how many respondents answered 'yes' across the whole sample

I tried using apply((x1,2 function(x) sum( head(x, 2:4))). However, it didnt work. Anyone could advise a more clever way of doing it? Much appreciated!

```
x1 <- structure(c(15L, 29L, 44L, 48L, 32L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 24L, 33L, 
14L, 29L, 25L, 33L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 9L, 18L, 41L), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(Q4Age = c("18 to 24", "25 to 29", 
"30 to 34", "35 to 39", "40 to 44", "45 to 49", "50 to 54", "55 to 59", 
"60 to 64", "65 and over"), Q12 = c("No", 
"Yes")), .Names = c("Q4Age", "Q12"
)), class = "table")


  #yes
sum(x1[1:3,2])

#no
sum(x1[1:3,1])
```

Comment: you just have an extra comma in there:   `apply(x1,2,function(x) sum(head(x,2)))`

Answer (score 4):

You simply have an extra comma in your apply function.   (no need for a `,` between `function` and its value)

However, more simply, you can use `colSums`:

```
 colSums(x1[1:2, ])
```